typeError while loading image in pdf
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ctx.embedImage is not a function
"dependencies": {
"@apollo/client": "^3.9.6",
"@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
"@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
"@pdf-lib/fontkit": "^1.1.1",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
"@react-pdf/layout": "3.6.4",
"@react-pdf/primitives": "^2.0.2",
"@react-pdf/renderer": "3.1.14",
"@redux-devtools/extension": "^3.2.3",
"@seatsio/seatsio-react": "^12.0.0",
"@types/hapi__joi": "^17.1.14",
"@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
"@types/node": "^20.11.19",
"@types/react": "^16.14.56",
"@types/react-color": "^3.0.5",
"@types/react-datepicker": "^2.11.1",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.9.24",
"@types/react-image-crop": "^8.1.3",
"@types/react-map-gl": "^5.2.11",
"@types/react-router": "^5.1.17",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.1",
"@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
"@types/shortid": "0.0.29",
"@types/styled-components": "^5.1.15",
"apollo-cache-persist": "^0.1.1",
"apollo-client": "^2.6.8",
"apollo-link": "^1.2.13",
"apollo-link-debounce": "^2.1.0",
"apollo-link-error": "^1.1.12",
"apollo-upload-client": "^12.1.0",
"compression": "^1.7.4",
"d3": "^5.16.0",
"escape-html": "^1.0.3",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"fast-deep-equal": "^3.1.3",
"framer-motion": "^1.11.1",
"graphql": "16.8.1",
"is-hotkey": "^0.1.8",
"mime-types": "^2.1.33",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.37",
"polished": "^3.7.2",
"proxy-deep": "^3.1.1",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-color": "^2.18.1",
"react-datepicker": "^3.8.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"react-dropzone": "^11.7.1",
"react-image-crop": "^8.6.12",
"react-map-gl": "^5.3.21",
"react-masonry-component": "^6.3.0",
"react-phone-input-2": "^2.14.0",
"react-popper": "^2.2.5",
"react-redux": "^7.2.9",
"react-router": "^5.3.4",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
"react-scripts": "^4.0.0",
"react-select": "^5.7.2",
"react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
"redux": "^4.1.1",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
"seatsio": "^69.1.0",
"shortid": "^2.2.16",
"slate": "^0.58.3",
"slate-history": "^0.58.3",
"slate-hyperscript": "^0.58.3",
"slate-react": "^0.58.3",
"styled-components": "^5.3.5",
"url": "^0.11.0",
"use-places-autocomplete": "^1.9.4"
},
"overrides": {
"@react-pdf/font": "2.2.1",
"@react-pdf/pdfkit": "2.1.0",
"@react-pdf/textkit": "4.2.0"
},

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
